# IOS Debug Build without Developer Account

Tags: codenameone, iphone-developer-program

I tried to setup a localbuild env. on my mac, installed Netbeans and the plugin but it seems to be deprecated so i couldnt get Xcode5 to properly build a project.

According to Shai, letting the certificate stuff empty in the project settings should allow a build on the cn1 servers which only works on jailbroken devices, this would be enough for me as i want to test the app and also be able to show to my Professors.

When trying to send in a Debug Build, i get this error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\xy\workspace\xyz\build.xml:344: The App id for an iOS build MUST be defined! See the project properties iOS section. For further information check this: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-code-signing-fail-checklist.html
```

Answer (score 1):

That was true until 2015 when we removed that functionality as it was causing a lot of problems for developers and required jailbreaking the devices: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deprecations-simplified-cn1lib-installs-theme-layering.html

A lot of our support overhead was related to problems with that process.

Comment: Hi Shai, so at the moment there is no such functionality for testing it on an iOS device beside of having an official Apple Developer Account

Comment: No. It's pretty much a requirement to run on a device even if you use xcode. Newer versions of xcode allow you to debug with a cable connected to the device but don't allow sideloading.